# Wordpress & Mod Rewrite

Tags: wordpress

I have Wordpress installed in a subdirectroy on my site (mysite.com/wordpress) while the site is displayed using mod rewrite as just mysite.com

This works fine for the backend of CiviCRM, but it is causing problems on the frontend. CiviCRM writes up URLs as mysite.com/wordpress/civicrm?etc which works fine on the backend, however, upon clicking on the links on the frontend the URLs are rewritten to mysite.com/civicrm?etc, which causes the links to fail and takes the user to a WP Page that says

CiviCRM

Do not delete this page. Page content is generated by CiviCRM.

How can I fix this? Is there a way to prevent WP from rewriting those URLs? Or is there a way to properly Configure CiviCRM when WP is installed in a subdirectory?

Edit: It turns out I indirectly came across a solution to this in another question I asked. The URL is here: [CiviCRM/Wordpress "Page" Integration](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6441/civicrm-wordpress-page-integration)

Comment: Have you installed WP in a subdirectory according to this codex document - https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory  or are you just using rewrite rules?

Comment: I followed the codex document rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make this work, though I don't know if it is a solution or a workaround...

I made a page called Wordpress, and made the auto-generated CiviCRM page a child page of that page. Therefore the URL of that page is mysite.com/wordpress/civicrm and I suppose because that page exists, WP does not try to rewrite it? For some reason, it works now...

Comment: I think this is more of a workaround.   I just created a test site with WP in a subdirectory and CiviCRM is not happy.  The real issue is that the CiviCRM Resource URL is being used for both front end and back end.   Set it nice for front end and backend goes nuts.   creating a slug to make Civi happy works around the issue, but it's not a solution.   Can you create an issue for this on https://issues.civicrm.org?